# Runtime Exception address out of range in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

I am currently trying to create a program which would ask the user how many items they have and then how many coupons they have. Then they would have to input how much the coupon is for. Everything runs fine up until it asks the user to enter the price for the coupon. It has an issue with the line

```
sw $t2, arr2($a3)
```

and says

```
Runtime exception at 0x004001a4: address out of range 0x200202a0
```

This is my first time working with arrays and im not too sure what I could do to fix it.

here is my code for reference

```
.data
    prompt1: .asciiz "How many items are you purchasing? \n"
    prompt2: .asciiz "\nPlease enter the price for item "
    prompt3: .asciiz ": "
    prompt4: .asciiz "Please enter the number of coupons that you want to use:\n"
    prompt5: .asciiz "Please enter the amount of coupon "
    
    
    error1: .asciiz "There are too many items that you are purchasing\n"
    error2: .asciiz "Price must be greater than 0"
    error3: .asciiz "Too many coupons!!\n"
    error4: .asciiz "This coupon is unacceptable\n"
    
    arr1: .word 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    arr2: .word 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    
.text   

main:
    la $a2, arr1
    la $a3, arr2
    
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt1     #prints prompt1
    syscall
    
    li $v0, 5
    syscall         #asks for user input
    
    add $s0, $v0, $0    #store input to $s0
    add $a1, $s0, $0    #pass the argument to $a1
    bgt $s0, 20, error  #branch if greater than 20
    blt $s0, 0, error   #branch if less than 0
    
    jal loop        #jump and link to loop
    
coupon:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt4     #print prompt2
    syscall 
    
    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    
    add $s1, $v0, $0        #save input to $s1
    add $a2, $s1, $0        #pass argument to $a2
    bgt $a2, $a1, couponError2  #if its greater than total products, then error
    
    jal loop2
    
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
    
error:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, error1
    syscall         #print error message
    
    j main
    
priceError:
    
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, error2
    syscall         #print error message
    
    j fillPriceArray

couponError:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, error4
    syscall         #print error message
    
    j fillCouponArray
    
couponError2:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, error3
    syscall         #print error message
    
    j coupon
    
    
loop:
    add $t1, $0, $a1    #put $a1 to $t1
    add $t4, $0, 1      #create a counter for coupon
    addi $t0, $0, 1     #create a counter $t0
    addi $t3, $0, 0

fillPriceArray: beq $t3, $t1, exit
    
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt2     #print prompt2
    syscall 
    
    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t0       #print number
    syscall
    
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt3     #print prompt 3
    syscall
    
    li $v0, 5
    syscall         #ask for user input
    
    add $t2, $v0 ,$0
    
    blt $t2, 0, priceError
    
    sw $t2, 0($a2)  #store input to arr1
    addi $a2, $a2, 4
    
    addi $t0, $t0, 1
    addi $t3, $t3, 1
    
    j fillPriceArray
    
loop2:
    move $t1, $0
    move $t2, $0
    move $t3, $0
    move $t0, $0
    
    addi $t0, $0, 1 
    add $t1, $0, $a2
    
    j fillCouponArray
    
fillCouponArray: beq $t0, $t1, exit

    la $t5, 0($a2)
    
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt5     #print prompt5
    syscall 
    
    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t0       #print number
    syscall
    
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt3     #print prompt 3
    syscall
    
    li $v0, 5
    syscall         #user input
    
    add $t2, $v0, $0    #save user input to $t2
    
    bgt $t2, $t5, couponError   #if #t2 is greater than $t5 error
    
    sw $t2, arr2($a3)   #save to element in array
    addi $a3, $a3, 4    #add to get to next element
    add $a2, $a2, 4     #add to get to next element
    
    addi $t0, $0, 1     #add for counter
    
    j fillCouponArray

exit:
    jr $ra
```

Comment: It seems to me like `$a3` contains the address of `arr2`. So when you do `sw $t2, arr2($a3)` you're basically doing something akin to `sw $t2, arr2+arr2($0)`. Just remove the offset and do `sw $t2, ($a3)` instead.

Comment: Thank you that seemed to help.